# java.lang.nullPointerException while performing Socket programming..How to use same socket object

Tags: java, android, sockets

Password.java

```
package com.example.vnc;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class Password extends MainActivity{

 Button submit;
   EditText pass;
   String data;

  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.sec);
submit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        data=pass.getText().toString();

            try{
                PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(soc.getOutputStream(),true);
                out.write(data);
                out.close();
            }
            catch(UnknownHostException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                }



    Intent next2=new Intent(Password.this,Security.class);
        startActivity(next2);
    }
});
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
   package com.example.vnc;

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.net.Socket;
   import java.net.UnknownHostException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
   Button connect;
   EditText ipadd,portadd;
   Socket soc;
    String ip,port;
      int port1;
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  connect=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ipadd=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        portadd=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        ip=ipadd.getText().toString();
        port=portadd.getText().toString();
        port1=Integer.parseInt(port);

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
        try{
            soc=new Socket(ip,port1);
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Connecting to Server"+ip,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent next1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Password.class);

        startActivity(next1);

    }
  });
}
```

}

This is in android. the MainActivity class has Socket connection and I am extending the MainActivity class. I am using the same socket soc at printwriter and it gives me error null pointer exception at printwriter line.

Please tell me what to do? how can I use same socket over 2 class

Comment: What does the log cat say?

Comment: java.lang.nullPointer at Printwriter line in Password.java file..

Comment: it was error but i have solved it. now i want to use same socket object in 2 different class

Comment: How is this different from your earlier question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126302/java-lang-nullpointerexception-while-performing-socket-programing - please don't repost more or less the same questions. Instead edit them in case you have additional information.

Comment: sorry about that but in earlier question I was getting error because of port1.and now I have logical error. I want to use same socket object in 2 diff class. next time i'll edit my post instead repost.

Answer (score 0):

The instance of `Password` is different from the `MainActivity` instance. Hence they do nog share state, and thus the `soc` instance var is empty. You might try to pass it along when you start the `Password` activity. You can do that using [`Intent.putExtra`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).